# Optimizing the following recursive function

Tags: c

trying to solve an assignment question...

info I have is:

```
foo(0)=0
foo(1)=1
foo(2)=2
```

the below code works upto approximately 30 numbers...but it needs to work fluently until 100, so I need to optimize it. I tried to create an equation which links every successive number but it did not work. Any ideas how to optimize it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

long foo(int n) {
  long a;
  if (n==0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if(n==1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else if(n==2)
  {
    return 2;
  }

  else
  {
   return foo(n-1)-2*foo(n-2)+foo(n-3)-2;
  }
}

int main(void) {

  long b=foo(7);

  printf("%ld",b);
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of memoization?

Comment: possibly on your system `long` is a 32 bit value. You should use standard data types `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`

Comment: Are you required to use recursion? If not, then don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple problem, you can make the function iterative.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t foo (int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 2)
        return 2;
    else
    {
        uint64_t a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
        uint64_t ret;
        for (int i = 2; i<n; i++)
        {
            ret = a + 2*b + c - 2;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = ret;
        }
        return (ret);
    }
}
```

If you have to use recursion, you can significantly improve runtime with memoisation. In this case, you need an extra array to store the results of already calculated values.

```
uint64_t memo[101];  // size this array to the maximum value of n needed to be calculated.

uint64_t foo(int n) {
  uint64_t a;
  if (n==0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if(n==1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else if(n==2)
  {
    return 2;
  }

  else
  {
    if (memo[n] == 0)
    {
        a = foo(n-1)-2*foo(n-2)+foo(n-3)-2;
        memo[n] = a;
    }
    else
    {
        a = memo[n];
    }
    return a;    
  }
}
```

Comment: Recursion was a requirement for the question. I did not know about memoization before, guess it can be really useful to speed up recursive programs. Thanks a lot for the help!